# Angle of tangent line and line $y=0,z=x$ is constant

Tags: differential-geometry, angle

Show that the tangent lines to the regular parameterized curve $\alpha(t)=(3t,2t^2,2t^3)$ make a constant angle with the line $y=0,z=x$.

1) The tangent line at each point is given, I believe, by $\alpha'(t)=(3,4t,6t^2)$

2) So the angle this makes with $(x,0,x)$ is given I believe by $\frac{\arccos(u\cdot v)}{|u||v|}$?

$$\frac{\arccos(3tx+6t^2x)}{\sqrt{(2x^2)(9+16t^2+36t^4)}}$$

---

Two concerns, should $x$ in my line $y=0,z=x$ be parameterized by $t$? Clearly my dot product is wrong, since it won't give a constant angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:   the direction of the line is $\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)$

therefore you need to show that $\theta$ is constant, where $$\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac{(\underline{u}\cdot\underline{v})}{|\underline{u}||\underline{v}|}$$ and $\underline{u}=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)$ and $\underline{v}=\left(\begin{matrix}3\\4t\\6t^2\end{matrix}\right)$

Can you finish it?

Comment: Apparently I can't(finish it that is), replacing $x$ above with $1$, still doesn't look constant to me unfortunately.

Comment: @DifferentialGeometry: Is there a typo in the problem? I don't think it is a constant. Your formulation is correct except that the $\arccos$ should be on the whole fraction.

Comment: @KittyL  oops I think you're right, there must be a typo

Comment: It's not impossible that my eyes are deceiving me when reading the question, so here's the actual question from Do Carmos Differential geometry text, page 7

http://imgur.com/eYIJjJX

Comment: OK so it must be a typo in the textbook

Comment: Ahhh shame, not in the erata either. That's alright

Comment: unless of course we've got it all wrong and need to go back to school straight away...

Comment: Hahaha well thanks @DavidQuinn, you solved my concerns with the $(x,0,x)$ thing, so I'll accept :).

Comment: The curve is supposed to be given by $(3t, 3t^2, 2t^3)$. This now allows us to factorize the polynomial with repeated roots, which as the issue originally.
The problem is solved in some of the solutions published by the author.